# Terraform plan output: what is the encoding being used

Tags: terraform

I've saved `terraform plan -out=my-plan` and intend to save it to source control and inject further to custom tool for ingestion and performing testing etc.

However, the file contents of `my-plan` are jumbled and I'm wondering what the encoding used is.

What is the encoding being used for the Terraform plan file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this and is suitable for use [tfjson](https://github.com/palantir/tfjson)

Answer (score 11):

While the other tools mentioned here are useful, things change regularly in the Terraform space and third-party tools often aren't able to be kept up-to-date.

For some time now Terraform has directly supported viewing a plan file in the same human-readable format that is displayed at the time you run `plan`:

```
terraform show <filename>
```

Since v0.12 you can now also view a plan file in JSON format, which you could save to work on further with other tools:

```
terraform show -json <filename>
```

There's an explanation of the JSON schema at https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html. As of writing, note that:

> The output ... currently has major version zero to indicate that the format is experimental and subject to change. A future version will assign a non-zero major version ... We do not anticipate any significant breaking changes to the format before its first major version, however.

Answer (score 10):

The Terraform plan output is a binary format that is not designed to be used outside of Terraform. Technically you could probably serialise it using whatever Terraform uses to handle the format but there is no stable API for this and could change at any point.

One of the Hashicorp employees ([Phinze](https://github.com/phinze)) briefly covered this in this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7976

One, probably reasonably fragile, option would be to simply parse the text output from running `terraform plan`. I use [Terraform Landscape](https://github.com/coinbase/terraform-landscape) to format plan outputs locally when working with JSON diffs that Terraform doesn't handle at all and that copes with this fine. However it also tends to break on the "minor" version upgrades (eg 0.9 to 0.10) as Terraform doesn't specify this as an API at all. [Terraform Plan Parser](https://github.com/lifeomic/terraform-plan-parser) also parses the textual output and notes that it is very much not to be used with the binary output.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to use terraform plan parser.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform was using [gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) format to encode/decode plan till [version 0.11.x](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.11.12/terraform/plan.go#L233)
This changed on terraform version [0.12](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.12.7/plans/planfile/tfplan.go#L367), they started using protocol buffer.

The `tfjson` project might not be working for 0.11.x and 0.12.x unless you rewrite the dependencies over there

Answer (score 0):

As of the date of this answer (24 October 2023), the `terraform plan` output file is a Zip archive containing the following files:

```
$ tf plan -out terraform.tfplan
$ unzip terraform.tfplan -d unzipped-plan
Archive:  terraform.tfplan
  inflating: unzipped-plan/tfplan    
  inflating: unzipped-plan/tfstate   
  inflating: unzipped-plan/tfstate-prev  
  inflating: unzipped-plan/tfconfig/m-/main.tf  
  inflating: unzipped-plan/tfconfig/modules.json  
  inflating: unzipped-plan/.terraform.lock.hcl
```

The Zip archive is created in the function [`Create()`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/53c34ff49cfbc1f70d7cdd3dca8040551c53737a/internal/plans/planfile/writer.go#L61).

The unzipped `tfplan` file is a protobuf-based serialization format that is created in the function [`writeTfPlan()`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/53c34ff49cfbc1f70d7cdd3dca8040551c53737a/internal/plans/planfile/tfplan.go#L468).